# Unable to push code using TFS

Tags: .net, tfs, version-control

I am using TFS. When I am adding a new file to the project and going to commit the changes and trying to push it, is giving an error:

> Error encountered while pushing to the remote repository: Not a valid reference 'origin/mybranchname'

Comment: Which version of TFS and VS do you use? Does it have any other error messages? What about commit/push the changes with Git command line, "git commit -m "first commit" "git push" Could you please share the details steps to reproduce this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Please try below items to fix the issue:

- Do a **fetch** and then a **merge**, or do a **pull**, to integrate
  the incoming commits with your local commits, and then try to push. See [this issue](http://howtoprogram.eu/question/git-visual-studio-push-existing-project-to-remote-server,61850) for details.

> For some reason the Visual Studio extension is misinterpreting the
>   error message from the git command and/or server. The actual problem
>   here is that you have incoming commits that should be fetched and
>   merged with your local commits before pushing. You're not allowed to
>   push multiple tips onto the server.

- Clean the VS client caches, restart VS, then try it again.
- Remove the Git and reinstall the latest version

  1. Backup and delete `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
     14.0\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\Git"` delete the Git folder.
  2. Remove Git by going to Control Panel > Program and Features
  3. Install latest version of GIT: https://git-scm.com/download/win

Comment: @Param Have you resolved the issue by above suggestions? any update?